# Angular CLI 6 coverage with --watch=false returns error

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

When I run

```
ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --no-progress
```

I get

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".watch" should be boolean.
```

I searched but can't find a hit for this error.

The docs (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test) clearly say --watch=false should work.

Other people say it works, for example https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10711#issuecomment-387704999

I'm on angular/cli 6.2.4.
angular 6.1.9

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: `ng test --watch=false` prior to yesterday worked. I now receive the same error.

Comment: It seems that CLI v6.2.4 isn't handling this parameter. We went to 6.1.5 and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have more than one project in your angular workspace (angular.json)?
I have received this error when running `ng test --watch=false` on a workspace with multiple projects.

You can run the test command on the project by name e.g.

```
ng run PROJECT_NAME:test --watch=false --code-coverage --no-progress
```

you need to substitute in the name of your project for `PROJECT_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

try `singleRun: true,` in karma.conf.js configuration, if you want the test to keep on watching for change and running the test automatically.

Comment: Hi. What I want is for 'ng test' without coverage to watch for changed files, but *not* 'ng test --code-coverage'